# Keeping a cell formula set to the same cell even when a row is inserted

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, excel-online

I have one sheet that needs to pick up singles sells for a lot of other sheets.
On the other sheets I have to change the information each month and I work across the rows so I insert a row at the top of the information each month. e.g on the sheet I pick info up from cell `e13` is a formula `=b13+c13-d13` and I need to pick up the answer from `e13` each month.  I want my main sheet to pick up from cell `e13` each month and not change to `e14`.

Does anyone know how I can do this please? The `$` does not work and I have also tried a few other things which haven't worked.

Comment: "the $ does not work and I have also tried a few other things which haven't worked." It may help to explain exactly what you have tried. Please [edit] your question with further information.

Comment: As ever, you will get the most efficient and effective help if you share a link to your sheet (or a copy of the sheet) here, being sure to set the sharing permission on the link to "Anyone with the link can edit."

Comment: @ErikTyler The OP's question should provide ALL the information to be able to understand the problem and the solution without requiring a spreadsheet as well. In this case however, I suggest that a spreadsheet would add little value. since the data relationships are clearly described in the question.

Comment: @Tedinoz, I suggest that you answer the question if you understand it as posted. I'm not sure I understand the intent of your personal comment to me (another contributor) here in response to my making the common request for a shared link to the sheet.

Comment: @ErikTyler Please do not take offense. None was intended and I don't mean to discourage contributors. A while ago, I had requested a spreadsheet and TheMaster brought this to my attention: [Is it ethical to ask for a Google sheets file, when answering a question, even when such request violates a user's privacy?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304/1330560). In hindsight, I might have done something similar instead of the form of words that I used to you. In any event, I've come to share the view that a question should be self-contained - this is what prompted my ill-worded comment to you.

Comment: @Tedinoz, thank you for clarifying. A far as I've ever seen, on this site and others like it, requesting a link to a sheet, or a copy of the sheet with confidential data swapped with dummy data, or a representative sheet is the norm. As far as I can figure, it would never be an ethical issue, since it would be up to the user to provide access to a sheet that either didn't contain personal data, or one which they put a little work into adapting or creating for the purpose of getting help. This is also a volunteer service. No one is forcing a user to share anything, ever, to my knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Use `INDIRECT` to reference a specific cell. You can write the sheet/cell references longhand in the formula, or build it using variables.

Let's say that you have a sheet "Working", and a sheet "Main". "Working" has a new row inserted every month; "Main" must maintain a link to "Working" Cell E13 despite the new row.

In the relevant cell of "Main", insert this formula:

`=indirect("Working"&"!E13")`

This will ALWAYS reference cell E13, regardless of how many rows are inserted on "Working".